# Stop the loop at the first object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am struggeling with this foor loop. I want to get the "customers" most recent order and store it in my database. But when I do this loop I get both the orders, the failed one and the recent one.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

    var TestOrdersXML = <testOrders _key="@testOrderId" operation="insertOrUpdate"/>;

    if (json[i].testOrderId != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@testOrderId = json[i].testOrderId;
    if (json[i].customerId != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@customerId = json[i].customerId;
    if (json[i].status != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@status = json[i].status;
    if (json[i].installationOrderData.state != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@state = json[i].installationOrderData.state;


   logInfo("Status: " + json[i].status + " STATE: " + json[i].installationOrderData.state);
    //collection.appendChild(TestOrdersXML);
  }
```

The log:

```
Status: FAILED State: failed 
Stauts: SUCCESS State: BOOKED
```

This is the array with two objects.

```
[
    {
        "installationOrderData":{
            "state": "booked"
        },
        "customerId": 123456,
        "testOrderId": 123456,
        "status": SUCCESS
    },
    {
        "installationOrderData":{
            "state": "failed"
        },
        "customerId": 123456,
        "testOrderId": 123456,
        "status": FAILED
    }
]
```

The question I am asking is, how do I only get the most recent object?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know which is the most recent object?

Comment: always the 0 in the array.

Comment: Ok; have you tried `json[0]`?

Comment: Most recent object based on what?

Comment: No, you mean as the second statement in the loop?

Comment: Ok, instead of recent, lets say the first object in the array.

Comment: To get the first item in an array you can just use `array[0]`, in this case `json[0]`, you don't need a loop for it

Comment: So I don't really need a foor-loop in this case, right?

Comment: @MartinGustafsson I don't think so; `for` loops are typically used when you want to repeat something a given number of times, to access a single item in an array you use the square bracket notation for instance `array[index]`

Answer (score 0):

**To get the first item / object in the array**

To get the first item in the array use `[0]`.

Arrays are 0 index based, so item at possition `[0]` will always be your first.

example:

```
let array = [1,2,3]
array[0] // 1
array[1] // 2
array[2] // 3
```

**To stop the loop in the first item / object in array**

simply add `return;` after your logic within the `loop`. Although i'm not sure why you'd want to do this.

example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   // do something here..
   return;

}
```